# Class Loading issue in Wildfly 16

Tags: java, xml, jboss, wildfly

During my migration from weblogic to wildfly 16, I need to implement the concept of a shared library but all I am is getting class loading issues. I am new to the concept of modules.

I created a folder for the library with jars in modules and created a module.xml. I used jboss-deployment-structure.xml to map the dependency to the shared library. The EAR gets the external jar but I am getting a class not found for the jar inside the EAR. It seems the jar inside the EAR is being excluded when I add the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to the EAR. Without the 
jboss-deployment-structure.xml I am able to deploy and login to my application but cant implement the functionalities of the shared jar.

[image]

The above image is the jboss-deployment-structure.xml I used.

[image]

The above image is the module.xml I used.

[image]

This is the server log I got on deployment with reference to the module created, It shows that the file "FileItem" is not found in the location I created but the jar with that class is already present in the EAR. Why is it not being read ?

Comment: Hi Nibin, please avoid posting images of text. Instead, include the actual text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error in the screenshot, JBoss is not able to resolve your dependency `com.lib`. The module you created i.e. `com.lib` should be present in one of the following locations :

1. $JBOSS_HOME/modules/
2. $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base

e.g. For location according to 1, The directory structure will be like :

> $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/lib/main

You will have following files at this location

- module.xml
- ebsUtility.jar
- SessionHandler.jar

Comment: Hi Abhijeet,

Thanks for your reply. But the module I created is in the module folder of JBOSS. The error I get is this "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem" but it is already present in a jar in the EAR.

Comment: @NibinGeorge is your modules depends on any other classes/modules? Also org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem is part of which jar and where is it located?

Comment: The other dependent jars are in the EAR itself. I only need the sessionhandler.jar to be in a shared location because it is shared by other applications also.

Comment: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem is part of which jar? I think org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem is required by your sessionhandler.jar file because of which you are getting this error

Comment: Your module must be 'self' sufficient so it should contains all the classes it is going to load either as jars in the module or as a dependency

Comment: Yes. Thats my observation as well. @NibinGeorge Check if these jars depends on any other jars/modules